# Can menus be auto-generated from discovered content?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am considering Drupal to host technical manuals. Aspects:

- the manuals change frequently
- I would bulk update the pages via *curl*, *ftp*, or some other method to be determined (point being: there will be zero hand editing in the Drupal interface). This upload would happen once a month.
- the manuals have nested Tables of Content that I want a *taxonomy based menu* to follow. These TOC change frequently.
- I could embed metadata (a tag maybe?) in the pages to support menu building

**Example content, before and after update:**

*BEFORE an update I may have this TOC and node structure*

```
Chapter 1
    Section A
    Section B
Chapter 2
    Section A
    Section B
    Section C
```

*AFTER an update I may have this TOC and node structure*

```
Chapter 1
    Section A
    Section B
    Section C
Chapter 2
    Section A
        Subsection I
        Subsection II
    Section B
```

Of course, menus need to change to reflect the new content I just uploaded.

**The part I have not figured out:**

*(assume I have Drupal Core 7.38, and any stable and active modules you might suggest)*:

> **Question** After I bulk create or bulk update content---can the corresponding menus be generated auto-magically by reading the new content I just uploaded? Or does it have to be hand-entered?

I hope my Q made sense. I hope Drupal can discover/build menus without custom PHP.

Any suggestions on Drupal configuration or publishing workflow are welcome.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the corresponding menus" here? What criteria do you have that would let whatever process you end up using know which menu a particular piece of content should be added to? I think fleshing that out a bit more will make it much easier to suggest specific modules that can help, at the moment it's kind of a lots-of-different-ways-to-do-that-depending-what-you-mean type of situation

Comment: Clive, I made edits that I hope clarify.

Comment: Thanks, still the same question, though - how are you planning to tell Drupal about your menu hierarchy? What format is _your_ version of that hierarchy data in? At the client end, how are you relating that hierarchical data to the content items?

Comment: In similar past projects, for each chunk of content, I'd import: 1) *ID-of-self*, 2) *child-of-ID*, 3) *menu-text*, 4) *content-html*. I did this in attributes of <div>. Then I'd use xslt to generate the menus. I'm not yet familiar enough with Drupal to know how to bulk import those metas in a helpful manner. The good news: I can change my content production to something Drupal likes.

Comment: I think I might have a direction for your - but it involves rethinking your Drupal structure; namely doing away with taxonomy, using entity reference and utilizing feeds.     If you would like to chat some, I am happy to do a screen share and Skype to show you what I have done.